# String.Split with a String?

Tags: c#, .net

I have what is probably a very simple question.

I want to do a classic `String.Split()`, but with a string, not a character.  Like `string.Split("word")` and get back an array just like if I had done `string.Split('x')`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split(string[], StringSplitOptions options)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx).

The code will look like:

```
var results = theString.Split(new[] {"word"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an available function overload on `string.Split` but it takes an array and an enum.

```
string test = "1Test2";
string[] results = test.Split(new string[] { "Test" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Will yield an array containing "1" and "2".